# Assign values to C# variables by reading characters from a text file

Tags: c#

I have a task that requires setting the int variables in a **C#** method from a line in a text file, running through the program and then repeating but with variables from the second line of the text file.

Each line of the text file would look similar to this

```
3 5 10
2 7 15
```

I am new to C# and am learning fast but have hit a brick wall with this one. Any help of suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code please - we're not a code writing service.

Comment: [StreamReader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader)

Comment: Thanks for the help and answers everyone. This was my first post on the site and I realise now that i should have submitted what i had tried first. The task i needed this for was self learning not work, Thanks again all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from the file, you can use the [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, or [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then you can use [`String.Split(new[] {' '})`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an array of strings (each one containing the number as a string) from the line.

Converting to an integer is easy, just `foreach` through and use the [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to change each to type `int`.

Keep in mind we're not here to write code for you, and there are quite a few answers to your question out there if you just break down what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Reading text from a file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Use Split() to turn "3 5 10", for example, into an array of strings  like "3", "5", "10". Then use int.Parse() to change each item in the array into an int.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple LINQ expression:

```
int[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .SelectMany(f => f.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(f => Convert.ToInt32(f))
    .ToArray();
```

First, you read all lines into a `string[]`. Then you use `SelectMany` to split all lines into the numbers you have and at the end, you cast to `int`.